# cant connect SharePoint with sharepointconnector npm package

Tags: sharepoint-addin, angular2

I have [sharepointconnector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharepointconnector) in my angular2 app. And I am trying connect SharePoint as I see in tutorials but here is error and my code.

```
export class HomeComponent { 
    constructor(){
        var sharepoint = require('sharepointconnector')({
  username : 'myname@domainname.onmicrosoft.com',
  password : 'mypassword',
  type : 'ntlm',
  url : 'https://yeneryilmaz1-3200ef41d84877.sharepoint.com'
});
sharepoint.login(function(err){
    debugger
  if (err){
    return console.error(err);
  }
});
```

here is the message seem in console:
[image]

I am able to connect office 365 portal with same credentials. but something wrong here, how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

`sharepointconnector` will never work for angular 2, because `sharepointconnector` is nodejs module and intended to work with nodejs only (server side javascript).

You are trying to use it inside browser (client side javascript), which is not possible.

Comment: Okey I understood. so what do you offer instead of it. I also know some recommends using node js  as backend to send request remote server in angular&TS app. What do you advice can you help me

Comment: You can use SPServices (https://spservices.codeplex.com), or AngularJS and SharePoint 2013 REST API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx), like here: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1115141/rest-api-and-angularjs-for-sharepoint-and-online

Comment: You need to clarify your requirements. It is app model or not, online or on-premise. Do you want to send requests to sharepoint from server (backend) side or client side. It's better to ask another question taking into account all clarifications needed.